# Reading double numbers from txt

Tags: c, function, file

I am having trouble creating a function that reads numbers from a .txt file and then writes them to separate variables.

Here is the code I wrote, here I tried to only read four of the numbers to try if the code worked:

```
void read_prop_data(double *prop1, double *prop2, double *prop3, double *prop4) {
    FILE *file_pointer = fopen("prop_dati.txt", "r");
    if (file_pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(file_pointer, "%lf", prop1);
    fscanf(file_pointer, "%lf", prop2);
    fscanf(file_pointer, "%lf", prop3);
    fscanf(file_pointer, "%lf", prop4);

    printf("The values of the properties are: %lf %lf %lf %lf\n",
           *prop1, *prop2, *prop3, *prop4);

    fclose(file_pointer);
}

int main() {
    double prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4;
    read_prop_data(&prop1, &prop2, &prop3, &prop4);
    return 0;
}
```

and here are the first four lines of the file **prop_dati.txt**:

```
2
0.4
2
0.998
```

The following is what the function prints:

```
The values of the properties are: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

do you have any idea why my function doesn't actually read the numbers in the file?

Comment: Please show the main routine that calls the function, including where the variables are declared.

Comment: i added the main routine as you asked

Comment: Are you sure the code posted actually compiles?  you `return 1;` from a `void` function.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/sMTTarcs7). Make sure you saved your file with the numbers, and fix the `return 1;` warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some problems you should fix:

- add the standard include directives: `#include <stdio.h>`
- change the return type of `read_prop_data` to `int` and return the number of successful reads;
- test the return value of `fscanf()` to detect conversion errors.  I suspect the file contains other data before the first number... possibly a byte order mark (BOM) which `fscanf()` does not skip.
- only output the numbers read successfully.

Here is a modified version you can try:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int read_prop_data(double *prop1, double *prop2, double *prop3, double *prop4) {
    FILE *file_pointer = fopen("prop_dati.txt", "r");
    if (file_pointer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s: %s\n", "prop_dati.txt", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    int n = fscanf(file_pointer, "%lf %lf %lf %lf", prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4);
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("Read %d properties:", n);
        if (n >= 1) printf(" %lf", *prop1);
        if (n >= 2) printf(" %lf", *prop2);
        if (n >= 3) printf(" %lf", *prop3);
        if (n >= 4) printf(" %lf", *prop4);
        printf("\n");
    }
    if (n < 4) {
        // show the next 3 bytes
        printf("pending characters:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            c = fgetc(file_pointer);
            if (c == EOF) {
                printf(" EOF");
                break;
            } else {
                printf(" %02X", (unsigned char)c);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(file_pointer);
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    double prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4;
    read_prop_data(&prop1, &prop2, &prop3, &prop4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
if i try to run this code it gives me:

"pending character is FF"

Comment: it prints me "pending characters EOF", what could cause this?
the file is definitely not empty

Comment: The file exists but it is empty

Comment: Nevermind, I'm stupid and didnt save the file, thank you for the reply!